# Company completion very slow

Tags: company-mode

I use `company` for completion, and it's fast and efficient in OCaml, Tuareg, and Merlin.

However, it is very slow in my C project.  For example, it takes more than 10 seconds when it suggests completions for structure, during which I cannot do anything in Emacs.

An example of structure I use in my project :

```
typedef struct {
  char name[D_NAME_MAXLEN];      /**< name of the disk */
  uint32_t size;   /**< size of the disk */
  uint32_t npart;   /**< number of partitions */
  uint32_t part[D_PARTMAX];    /**< parition sizes */
} d_stat;
```

Then I have a d_stat pointer caled d_stat and after typing typing `dstat->` it stops for a looong long time, even sometimes it bugs...

Same thing with the macros, I have some macros :

```
OPT_SIZE
OPT_LONG_SIZE
OPT_FORCE
OPT_LONG_FORCE
OPT_NAME
OPT_LONG_NAME
etc...
```

And when I type OPT_ it stops like above.

How can I speed up `company` completion when it gets this slow?  Right now, it is not usable.

I'm using `(global-company-mode)` in my init file.

tree of the project looks like :

```
syscp
├── bin
│   ├── disk.tfs
│   ├── libll.so
│   ├── libtfs.so
│   ├── tfs_analyze
│   ├── tfs_create
│   ├── tfs_format
│   └── tfs_partition
├── dev
│   └── device.tfs
├── disk.tfs
├── doc
│   └── config
├── ld
├── lib
│   ├── block0.h
│   ├── block.c
│   ├── block.h
│   ├── error.c
│   ├── error.h
│   ├── ll.c
│   ├── ll.h
│   ├── tfs.c
│   ├── tfs.h
│   ├── utils.c
│   └── utils.h
├── Makefile
├── obj
│   ├── block.o
│   ├── error.o
│   ├── libblock.o
│   ├── liberror.o
│   ├── libll.o
│   ├── libtfs.o
│   ├── ll.o
│   └── utils.o
├── README
├── setup.sh
└── src
    ├── default.h
    ├── tfs_analyze.c
    ├── tfs_create.c
    ├── tfs_format.c
    └── tfs_partition.c

7 directories, 39 files
```

Comment: I have added these informations in the post.

Comment: Is this a big project?

Comment: For me yes since I'm a student ! But it's just a school project... It's a library for a filesystem encoded in a file (inception !) with the ordinary tools to manipulate the filesystem like mkdir, etc... I put the tree in the post.

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't be too slow at this size. After all, completion is much faster than you describe inside the Emacs C sources. If you can send me the project itself (see the email in any of my GitHub repos), I will take a look.

Comment: On the other hand, `company-clang` (you do use Clang, right? see by typing `M-x company-diag`) is inherently only suitable for small-ish projects, because it calls Clang for every completion, and each time it scans all dependencies of the current file. You can use some third-party daemon-based backend for improved performance, such as `irony-mode` or `rtags`.

Comment: Yes I use Clang, the problem may come from it.
Have you tried iron-mode or rtags ? If so which one would you recommend me to give a first try ?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't develop in C or C++, but you can refer to https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3y6czz/emacs_and_cc_irony_or_rtags_orboth/. Admittedly, the current practices are a bit of a mess.